# how to change with expression rdlc borderwidth?

Tags: c#, rdlc

How with expression change BorderWidth (row)?
I found this

```
=iif(Fields!AccountType.Value = "1", "Bold", "Normal")
```

i want same - but for BorderWidth! 
10x

Comment: ...more details? You want us to help you, right?!

Comment: =IIF(Fields!TheType.Value = "sumTotal", "Bold", "Default") - use this code to change FontWeight...but similarly, how to change BorderWidth ?

Comment: You want to change from what to what, based on what condition?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!AccountType.Value = "1", "2pt", "1pt")
```

You can set `BorderWidth.Default` for every borders or specify different `Left`, `Right`, `Top`, `Bottom` border width.